# How to tell if someone is looking at one of the records on your database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to add some fake records/rows for in the table for MS SQL 2008 Standard Edition database and use these records to monitor my database.

The purpose for this is to monitor hackers. It is possible to create a trigger to do this. It seemed like the DDL Triggers can not do this tasks.

Comment: Define "looking at." Exactly what sort of attack are you trying to defend against here? Most attacks these days are automated, anyway, so there isn't necessarily someone sitting at a computer "looking at" your private data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't control access to your database via stored procedures (where you could add your own logging), you will need to use auditing or server-side trace for this. There is no such thing as a select trigger and there are no DMVs that will tell you which rows were looked at via any select action.

Comment: One possible workaround would be to check the cached pages, but you still couldn't tell "who" looked at it or for what purpose, just what data was loaded from disk  to memory.

Comment: And this gives you pages, but not rows. So if his audit rows just happened to be on the same page as some other rows, that method might yield false positives. They also might be in memory for other reasons (e.g. index maintenance, a table-wide update, etc).