# Count columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table

`fnavn - lname - ... - countColumn

And for each `SELECT` I use on this table, I want `countColumn` to go up by one.

Is it possible?

Comment: If it is, it would probably involve a trigger or a stored procedure.  However, what you want sounds...very bizarre, and I'm certain that there's a better way to tackle this.  Why do you want such a counter?

Comment: I have a webservice that I want to count up each time you receive data from it. So I know what data is received the most.

Comment: Maybe not an exact dupe but [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7392662/73226)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), e.g.

```
select *, row_number() over(order by fnavn) as [count]
from MyTable
```

Comment: That numbers rows not columns but maybe that's what they need. unclear to me.